# Nested Destructuring in JavaScript Inside Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to declare the `orderItems` inside a nested object in my React app.
Sometimes `order` is null so `orderItems` is not found. So the error is of course `Cannot read property of orderItems of null`. How do I fix this?

```
 const { order: { orderItems = [] } = {} } = res.cartFind
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes order is null so orderItems is not found.

Since it's `null` (not `undefined`), we can't work around it with defaults (since they only apply to things that are missing or `undefined`, specifically). But since it's at the top level of `res.cartFind`, we can work around it with [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Remove the `{order: ....}` part and move `.order` to the end, then default it with `?? {}`, and destructure that:

```
const { orderItems = [] } = res.cartFind.order ?? {};
```

Live Example:

```js
function example(res) {
    const { orderItems = [] } = res.cartFind.order ?? {};
    console.log(orderItems);
}

console.log("When order is null:");
example({
    cartFind: {
        order: null,
    },
});

console.log("When order is not null:");
example({
    cartFind: {
        order: {
            orderItems: [1, 2, 3],
        },
    },
});
```

In comments I think you've asked what if `order` is there and it has `orderItems: null` in it. With the above, you'd end up with `null`, because (again) defaults only get used when something is missing or `undefined`.

The two things that handle both `undefined` **and** `null` (we call those "nullish" values) are nullish coalescing (which we used above), `??`, and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), `?.`.

If `order` may be missing, or it may be present but with `orderItems: null` in it, you can handle that with a combination of the two:

```
const orderItems = res.cartFind.order?.orderItems ?? [];
```

Here's how that works:

1. If `res.cartFind.order` is `null` or `undefined` (or missing,which is effectively `undefined`), then `res.cartFind.order?.orderItems` results in `undefined` (it doesn't throw an error the way it would if there weren't a `?` after `order`). If `res.cartFind.order` *isn't* `null` or `undefined` (nullish), then we try to get `orderItems` from it.
2. So now `res.cartFind.order?.orderItems` has been evaluated and given us either `undefined` or the value of `orderItems` (which may be anything). By using `thatResultValue ?? []` we're saying "use `thatResultValue` if it isn't `null` or `undefined`, but use `[]` if it is."

Live Example:

```js
function example(res) {
    const orderItems = res.cartFind.order?.orderItems ?? [];
    console.log(orderItems);
}

console.log("When order is null:");
example({
    cartFind: {
        order: null,
    },
});

console.log("When order is not null and has a valid orderItems:");
example({
    cartFind: {
        order: {
            orderItems: [1, 2, 3],
        },
    },
});

console.log("When order is not null but doesn't have orderItems:");
example({
    cartFind: {
        order: {
        },
    },
});

console.log("When order is not null and has orderItems but it's null:");
example({
    cartFind: {
        order: {
            orderItems: null,
        },
    },
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: if any variable found in the future inside res.cartFind.order that is null would be automatically be fine, right?

Comment: @Joseph - I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: if there objects, array or variables that is located inside `res.cartFind.order` that its value is undefined or null then I don't have to worry about getting that same error as mine before cause you already use the nullish coalescing?

Comment: Not with the code above getting `orderItems`, no.

Comment: @Joseph With `{ cartFind: { order: { orderItems: null } } }` you will end up with `const orderItems = null` as well, not an empty array. If you need to prevent that, you cannot use destructuring with default values, I recommend `const orderItems = res.cartFind.order?.orderItems ?? [];`.

Comment: Thanks guys @Bergi @T.J. How about this one? What would be a good look for this? This is different example by the way.
`data: { cartFind: { order: { orderItems} } = {} } = {}`

Comment: @Joseph That's incomplete, currently a syntax error. And like in the other cases, defaults in destructuring never handle `null` values.

Comment: @Bergi. this is the complete one `const {
    loading,
    error,
    data: { cartFind: { order: { orderItems} } = {} } = {},
  } = useQuery(GET_ORDER, {
    variables: { page: '111' },
  })`

Comment: @Joseph Ah, ok. But no, the problem is still the same.

Comment: @Bergi. How would fix it? if orderItems is sometimes null?

Comment: @Joseph - See the end of [Bergi's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517436/nested-destructuring-in-javascript-inside-objects/68517462?noredirect=1#comment121093107_68517462), they've already shown you how to handle that with a combination of [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: @Joseph See above. You'll need two statements, one to destructure `const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(…);`, the other to safely access `orderItems` from the data.

Comment: @Joseph - I've added to the answer to show handling `order: { orderItems: null }`.